# How to create a source that collects dynamic values

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I have read docs but somehow Unable to define the source I want.
I want to define a source which collects List of integers dynamically.

def getValue(m:Map[String,Int]):Int = m.getOrElse("#abcd",0)

Whenever I call this function I would like to collect the return value of it.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm not really sure what's being asked here. Maybe an example could help..

Comment: val src = Source.single("abcd xyz pqr") ; 
val sink = Sink.foreach[List[String]](x=> println(x)) 

def splitString(x:String) = x.split(" ").toList

src.map(splitString).runWith(sink) 



If you look at the "src" in the above code  - it is hard coded and it is just a single element, instead I would like to define a source that collects list of lines dynamically (presume Ive a function  from which I obtain strings on-the-fly and I want to append it to source) - Am I making sense?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but you could be looking for `Source.queue`. Example:

```
  val source: Source[Int, SourceQueueWithComplete[Int]] = 
    Source.queue[Int](16, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)

  val sink: Sink[Int, NotUsed] = ???

  val queue: SourceQueueWithComplete[Int] = source.to(sink).run()

  queue.offer(1)
  queue.offer(2)
  queue.offer(3)
```

Documentation [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#queue).